# Case in Arraylist complains of "orphaned case"

Tags: java, list, case

My problem is that, I made an arraylist using a `case` so the values are conditional, but the compiler complains that I have an "orphaned case". Why?

```
ArrayList<Integer> object = new ArrayList<Integer>();{
        case objid == 1:{
        object.add(objnum);
        object.add(objx);
        object.add(objy);}
```

Comment: Did you mean `if` instead of `case`?

Comment: ohh, so it should be if? Okay thanks :D that solved my problem i guess ^^

Comment: sum1 just said me earlier i should use case, but okies :)

Comment: omfg!! Problems rised inmediately from 1 to 74 and i have 5 mins left to do that..

Comment: Five minutes left? What is this, a live exercise in an exam?!? Pity one could only downvote a question a single time.

Comment: okay, gf my atk grade.. :<

Comment: yes, it's so late that i should go and i was doing atk's work, which means my whole number.. Dx

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a `case` statement without a `switch` statement.

A `switch` statement like the following:

```
switch (var) {
case 0:
  doSomething();
  break;
case 1:
  somethingElse();
  break;
default:
  anotherThing();
  break;
}
```

is (roughly) equivalent to

```
if (var == 0) {
  doSomething();
} else if (var == 1) {
  somethingElse();
} else {
  anotherThing();
}
```

So, just like it wouldn't make sense to say

```
if (0) {
  doSomething();
} // ...
```

it also doesn't make sense to have a `case` statement without anything to compare it *to*. In this sense, the `case` statement has no parent `switch` statement, so Java says that it's **orphaned**.

You could change your code to:

```
if (objid == 1) {
    object.add(obnum);
    object.add(objx);
    object.add(objy);
}
```

For more info on the `switch` statement, try [this document](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+switch&aq=f&oq=java+switch&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j65j60l3.1194&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Ty, really good answer but i just deleted that whole list.. i'm so dumb! Thank you anyway..

Answer (score 1):

```
case objid == 1:{
    object.add(objnum);
    object.add(objx);
    object.add(objy);
}
```

This is never valid Java. Did you mean `if`, like so?

```
if (objid == 1) {
    object.add(objnum);
    object.add(objx);
    object.add(objy);
}
```

To answer your second question, `ArrayList` should usually only be used when you no longer have direct access to its members, and thus need something like `x = object.get(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
ArrayList<Integer> object = new ArrayList<Integer>();
switch (objid) {
  case 1:
  {
     object.add(objnum);
     object.add(objx);
     object.add(objy);}
  }
```